# Como formatar um elemento HTML p/ ficar igual a um botão?

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

Eu adicionei um novo botão via *shortcode* na descrição da página do produto WooCommerce/WordPress. Eu gostaria de formatá-lo no mesmo *layout* do botão (inclusive o efeito *hover*).

O "Configure Agora!" é o segundo botão, que precisa ser visualmente igual o botão "Comprar" do meu template.

***Edit:***

Este é o código q o plugin "Popup" fornece para esta função:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sg-show-popup" data-sgpopupid="1" data-popup-event="click">Configure Agora!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso usando jQuery!

```
jQuery('.sg-show-popup').addClass('button');
```

Com esse código, você seleciona todos os itens que tiverem a class `.sg-show-popup` e adiciona a cada item dessa lista a class `button`. Basta adicionar esse script no seu tema, cortando a necessidade de editar o plugin.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Hamurabi. Vou fazer conforme você indicou :)

Olhando no seu perfil, vi que você joga CS:GO também. Me add p/ gente trocar uma idéia? ;D

https://steamcommunity.com/id/tibeh

Comment: Sim, claro! Assim que tiver acesso ao steam te adiciono.

Comment: Você desenvolve plugins para WordPress? Tem interesse em participar de um projeto para a comunidade? :)

http://bigcs.com.br/quem-somos/

Abraço!

Comment: Mandei a solicitação no Steam: marubah. Add que conversamos

Answer (score 0):

Bem, encontrei uma solução "paliativa". Digo isso pois não sei se é a forma correta.

Eu editei o arquivo do plugin que insere a classe no item. Especificamente este trecho do código:

```
        if(isset($args["wrap"])) {
        echo "<".$args["wrap"]." class='sg-show-popup ' data-sgpopupid=".@$args['id']." $attr data-popup-event=".$eventName.">".$content."</".$args["wrap"]." >";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='sg-show-popup button' data-sgpopupid=".@$args['id']." $attr data-popup-event=".$eventName.">".$content."</a>";
    }
}
```

EU inseri a mesma classe que o tema utiliza para estilizar o botão. A class "button".

Tem alguma outra forma de fazer, ou tudo bem manter assim? O problema aqui é que eu vou precisar editar esse arquivo sempre que o plugin for atualizado. =/

Answer (score 0):

Se você preferir, pode simplesmente adicionar a class `button` no elemento direto no html.